# Foreground service example

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments

I am new to android. Can anyone post the link or code for "android foreground service example with notification". I googled , but didn't get any example of foreground service.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Create a `Notification`, perhaps using `Notification.Builder` or `NotificationCompat.Builder`, and pass that to `startForeground()` on the service:

```
public class Downloader extends IntentService {
  private static int FOREGROUND_ID=1338;

  public Downloader() {
    super("Downloader");
  }

  @Override
  public void onHandleIntent(Intent i) {
    startForeground(FOREGROUND_ID,
                    buildForegroundNotification(filename));

    // do useful work here

    stopForeground(true);
  }

  private Notification buildForegroundNotification(String filename) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder b=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    b.setOngoing(true);

    b.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.downloading))
     .setContentText(filename)
     .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download)
     .setTicker(getString(R.string.downloading));

    return(b.build());
  }
}
```

(a trimmed-down service from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Notifications/Foreground))

Answer (score 2):

A better example would be:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Received Start Foreground Intent ");
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
notificationIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
notificationIntent, 0);

Intent previousIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
previousIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PREV_ACTION);
PendingIntent ppreviousIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
previousIntent, 0);

Intent playIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
playIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION);
PendingIntent pplayIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
playIntent, 0);

Intent nextIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
nextIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.NEXT_ACTION);
PendingIntent pnextIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
nextIntent, 0);

Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
R.drawable.truiton_short);

Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
.setContentTitle("Truiton Music Player")
.setTicker("Truiton Music Player")
.setContentText("My Music")
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
.setLargeIcon(
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(icon, 128, 128, false))
.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
.setOngoing(true)
.addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_previous,
"Previous", ppreviousIntent)
.addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play, "Play",
pplayIntent)
.addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_next, "Next",
pnextIntent).build();
startForeground(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID.FOREGROUND_SERVICE,
notification);
} else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.PREV_ACTION)) {
Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Clicked Previous");
} else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION)) {
Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Clicked Play");
} else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.NEXT_ACTION)) {
Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Clicked Next");
} else if (intent.getAction().equals(
Constants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Received Stop Foreground Intent");
stopForeground(true);
stopSelf();
}
return START_STICKY;
}
```

Took reference from a [tutorial here](http://www.truiton.com/2014/10/android-foreground-service-example/).. maybe of help to you